# Payment methods are not displayed, suddenly

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment-banktransfer

Suddenly, all payment methods are not shown in checkout. I have a custom payment method together with bank transfer payment, and none of them appears in checkout.

What may be happening?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Having the same issue, even after clearing browser cache, recompiling DI, refreshing static content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved, after I removed browser cache.